# How to get value from json in iOS Swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, alamofire

I have JSON with dynamic data of all key values. Right now I am trying to get value by finding "type = object" if an object exists then in values I will check the contentType exists in values.

How to find the value matched inside JSON and convert it into an array?

Here is my code:

```
  switch response.result {
        case .success:
            
            
            guard let data = response.value  else {
                return
            }
          
            if let JSON = response.value {

                let json = JSON as? [String: AnyObject]
                print("json view docue",json)

                
                if let castedDict = json as? [String: String] {
                    print("Converted successfully: \(castedDict)")

                } else {
                    print("Failed to cast the dictionary")
                }
               
                let vc = self.stringify(json: json)
                print("new json converted into string:::", vc.count)
                
                
                
                }
            
            self.view.removeLoading()
            
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error:", error)
            self.view.removeLoading()
        }
```

Here is my JSON:

```
    {
image1: {
   type = Object;
   value = "{\"contentType\":\"image/jpeg\",\"url\":\"https://www.pexels.com/photo/neon-advertisement-on-library-glass-wall-9832438/",\"fileName\":\"9832438.jpg\"}";
  valueInfo =     {
    objectTypeName = "com.google.gson.JsonObject";
    serializationDataFormat = "application/json";
   };
  },
 image2: {
   type = Object;
    value = "{\"contentType\":\"image/jpeg\",\"url\":\"https://www.pexels.com/photo/neon-advertisement-on-library-glass-wall-9832438/",\"fileName\":\"9832438.jpg\"}";
    valueInfo =     {
    objectTypeName = "com.google.gson.JsonObject";
    serializationDataFormat = "application/json";
     };
    }
  }
```

Any much appreciated pls...

Comment: Why not use Codable? You need to iterate over the dictionary, check the `type` value, then the `value` value, no?

Comment: Could you post the real json and explain a little better what you want to do, what does "get value" mean here? Or is it perhaps so that if you use Codable as suggested then this becomes trivial?